# Rails category (or filter) links in same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, model, controller

Having trouble understanding how using links_to filter content within the same controller in the rails view works. My code is below:

# index.html.erb (link nav area)

```
<nav>
    <%= link_to 'Daily Monitoring', root_path(:category => "dailymonitoring") %>
    <%= link_to 'Smoke Tests', root_path(:category => "smoketests") %> 
</nav>
```

# index.html.erb (cont.)

```
<ul id="results">
    <% if @reportlinks == "dailymonitoring" %>
         # dailymonitoring content
    <% elsif @reportlinks == "smoketests" %>
          # smoketests content
    <% end %> <!-- end conditional -->
</ul>
```

# reports_controller.rb

```
    if params[:category]
        @reportlinks = Report.where(:category => params[:category])
    else
        @reportlinks = Report.all
    end
```

# model (report.rb)

```
 class Report
   include ActiveModel::Model
   attr_accessor :reports, :smokereports
   belongs_to :reports, :smokereports, :reportlinks
 end
```

The error I'm getting is **undefined method `belongs_to' for Report:Class** and a **< top (required) >** error. There's no database involved. I'm just trying to make it known that I want to click on any of the links and that filters only the block of content within that if/else statement.

Do I need to create a new controller for the if/else statement to work? Please let me know if more code is needed to get a better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`belongs_to` is defined in `ActiveRecord::Associations`, which is part of `ActiveRecord`. You are manually including [`ActiveModel::Model`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) which doesn't offer any association-related capabilities.

> Includes the required interface for an object to interact with ActionPack, using different ActiveModel modules. It includes model name introspections, conversions, translations and validations. Besides that, it allows you to initialize the object with a hash of attributes, pretty much like ActiveRecord does.

Assuming you don't need the whole `ActiveRecord` database persistence capabilities but you need the association style, then you'll need to deal with that manually.

Therefore, you will have to define your own methods to append/remove associated records and keep track of them.

The association feature of ActiveRecord is strictly tied with the database persistence.